# How to attach a button groups to a card with Semantic-UI

Tags: semantic-ui

in the doc it says to add a "attached" class, it works for a single button but how to do the same things with a button groups ?

i also tried to add a "fluid" class but the buttons are then  one on the other

Thanks

```
<div class="ui card">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Elliot Fu</div>
    <div class="description">
    Elliot Fu is a film-maker from New York.
   </div>
  </div>
     <div class="ui bottom attached buttons ">
        <div class="ui labeled icon button">
          <i class="pause icon"></i>
          Pause
        </div>
        <div class="ui right labeled icon button">
          <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
          Next
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwynd2v9/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to specify how many buttons you have, with `two fluid buttons`

```
<div class="ui two bottom attached fluid buttons ">
```

Here's a fork of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txfLkcjp/1/